# How do I check if these 6 equations with 6 variables are solvable?

Tags: trigonometry, linear-transformations, kinematics

I have been trying to find 3 rotational matrices of a kinematic system. I have algebraically found 6 equations connecting the 6 variables (angles) that I want to find.

The six equations I have are:

\begin{array}{c}
\frac{25}{2}-\frac{6078\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rz}} \right)}{125}=\frac{25\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{2}+\frac{2797\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{125}\\
\frac{6078\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rx}} \right)\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rz}} \right)}{125}-\frac{3217\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rx}} \right)}{250}-71=\frac{25\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{2}-\frac{2797\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{125}-\frac{3217\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)}{250}\\
\frac{3217\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rx}} \right)}{250}+\frac{6078\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rz}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{0Rx}} \right)}{125}=\frac{3217\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)}{250}-\frac{2797\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)}{125}+\frac{25\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{2}
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{6078\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lz}} \right)}{125}-\frac{25}{2}=\frac{2797\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{125}-\frac{25\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{2}\\
\frac{6078\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lx}} \right)\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lz}} \right)}{125}-\frac{3217\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lx}} \right)}{250}-71=-\frac{3217\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)}{250}-\frac{2797\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{125}-\frac{25\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{2}\\
\frac{3217\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lx}} \right)}{250}+\frac{6078\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lz}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{0Lx}} \right)}{125}=\frac{3217\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)}{250}-\frac{2797\,\mathrm{cos}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)}{125}-\frac{25\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1x}} \right)\,\mathrm{sin}\left(t_{\textrm{1z}} \right)}{2}
\end{array}

I would like to get the solutions for the 6 "t".

I have attempted to solve this using the MATLAB solve and vpasolve, but it returns only the symbolic variables.

Is this actually solvable? What are the ways that I can tell?

I am clearly misunderstanding something, and would really appreciate some help! Thanks.

Comment: Nonlinear equations? Sounds like a possible job for Newton.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I'm not sure what you mean. Can you expand?

Comment: Use Newton's method. Or, in MATLAB, `fsolve` or similar.

Comment: It's worth noting that streamlining the appearance can help w/wrapping one's mind around solvability. Eg, writing "$x$" & "$x'$" for $\sin x$ & $\cos x$, replacing ugly fractions w/letters, and de-complicating the variables, your system is "simply" $$\begin{align} a-bp&=aq'+cq\\ a+bt&=aq'-cq\\ bp'r'-dr-e&=\phantom{-}aqs'-cq's'-ds\\ bt'u'-du-e&=-aqs'-cq's'-ds\\ bt'u \;+du'\phantom{-e}\;&=-aqs\,-cq's\;+ds'\\ bp'r \;+dr'\phantom{-e}\;&=\phantom{-}aqs\,-cq's\;+ds'\\ p^2+p'^{\,2}=\cdots&=1 \end{align}$$ Is it solvable? Maybe, maybe not. (TeM says yes.) But now there are clear avenues of approach.

Answer (score 1):

Set:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& a = \cos(t_{0Lx}), 
\quad \quad
b = \sin(t_{0Lx}),
\quad \quad
a^2 + b^2 = 1\,; \\
& c = \cos(t_{0Lz}), 
\quad \quad
d = \sin(t_{0Lz}),
\quad \quad
c^2 + d^2 = 1\,; \\
& e = \cos(t_{0Rx}), 
\quad \quad
f = \sin(t_{0Rx}),
\quad \quad
e^2 + f^2 = 1\,; \\
& g = \cos(t_{0Rz}), 
\quad \quad
h = \sin(t_{0Rz}),
\quad \quad
g^2 + h^2 = 1\,; \\
& k = \cos(t_{1x}), 
\quad \quad \;\,
l = \sin(t_{1x}),
\quad \quad \;\;
k^2 + l^2 = 1\,; \\
& m = \cos(t_{1z}), 
\quad \quad \;
n = \sin(t_{1z}),
\quad \quad \;\,
m^2 + n^2 = 1\,; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

it can be reduced to a *system of 12 polynomial equations* and this allow us to determine all the complex solutions by implementing an appropriate *numerical method* (read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4658876/247735)). Obviously, if we have a software equipped with a respectable CAS system (mainly *Mathematica*, *Maple* and *MatLab*) everything will be simpler and in lucky cases we could even get an exact solution.

Specifically, I tried in `Mathematica` by writing:

```
eqns = {25/2 - 6078/125 h == 25/2 m + 2797/125 n,
        6078/125 e g - 3217/250 f - 71 == 25/2 k n - 2797/125 k m - 3217/250 l,
        3217/250 e + 6078/125 g f == 3217/250 k - 2797/125 m l + 25/2 l n,
        -6078/125 d - 25/2 == 2797/125 n - 25/2 m,
        6078/125 a c - 3217/250 b - 71 == -3217/250 l - 2797/125 k m - 25/2 k n,
        3217/250 a + 6078/125 c b == 3217/250 k - 2797/125 m l - 25/2 l n,
        a^2 + b^2 == 1, c^2 + d^2 == 1, e^2 + f^2 == 1,
        g^2 + h^2 == 1, k^2 + l^2 == 1, m^2 + n^2 == 1};

sol = Solve[eqns, Reals];

Simplify[{t0Lx -> ArcTan[a, b], t0Lz -> ArcTan[c, d],
          t0Rx -> ArcTan[e, f], t0Rz -> ArcTan[g, h],
          t1x -> ArcTan[k, l], t1z -> ArcTan[m, n]} /. sol]
```

and in a moment we get *8 real exact solutions*. If it hadn't been possible to get them exact, it would have been enough to use `NSolve[]` to approximate them, however being careful to adjust `WorkingPrecision -> 10` ...